# Can "belongs_to" be defined more than once in Active_Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, activerecord, orm, forums

I am trying to write a database for a company in town. I am using Devise for authentication, and Forem for the forums of the site. I decided to just have one class, "Account" for the Devise authentication, which will have many different access types to the site.

The bulk of the users will be just customers, which are segregated by routes (not Rails routes, street routes). So I decided to have them have their own profile model.

I want to do this - Profile is linked to account, and to route. (Routes are named gmr_routes)

Is this code the proper way to do it? Documentation I've found hasn't told me I can't, but I just want to be sure....

```
    class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :street_address
        belongs_to :account
        belongs_to :gmr_route
    end
```

Account has a has_one relationship with Profile, and gmr_route has a has_many.

Is this right?

Bryan

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's perfectly acceptable.  You need to remember to include a foreign key id on any model with a belongs_to.

So in the case you describe, you would have `account_id:integer` and `gmr_route_id:integer` in your migration, and include those in the `attr_accessible` call in your model